# How to pass GUID from View to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to pass GUID through parameter from View to Javascript function. I got an error message in Firefox `identifier starts immediately after numeric literal`

Here is code in View

```
onchange="updateOrder(<%= Model.Category[j].OrderItems[i].OrderID %>, <%= Model.Category[j].OrderItems[i].ID %>, this.value, <%= Model.CategoryItems[j].OrderItems[i].Order.JournalID %>);" />

<%= Model.CategoryItems[j].OrderItems[i].Order.JournalID %> is in GUID
```

code in Javascript

```
function updateOrder(orderID, itemID, quantity, journalId) {
    ... 
}
```

Really appreciate it for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need some quotes:

```
onchange="updateOrder('<%= Model.Category[j].OrderItems[i].OrderID %>', '<%= Model.Category[j].OrderItems[i].ID %>', this.value, '<%= Model.CategoryItems[j].OrderItems[i].Order.JournalID %>');" />
```

Note though if there is any chance the ID values could contain a quote character, you're going to have to escape it. (I'm assuming all the IDs are strings (GUIDs). If any are numeric, you can remove the quotes.)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
onchange="updateOrder(<%= Model.Category[j].OrderItems[i].OrderID %>,
 <%= Model.Category[j].OrderItems[i].ID %>, this.value, 
'<%= Model.CategoryItems[j].OrderItems[i].Order.JournalID %>');" />
```

Notice the '' around JournalID parameter